# Is there a way to run a macro as part of an animation in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I know I can run a macro with an Action attached to a shape (wither with a click or a mouse over), but is there a way to run it as part of an Animation sequence?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way of embedding VBA in an animation, but I have
seen the following suggestions for working around this lack.

- Use
  [AutoEvents Add-in for PowerPoint](http://skp.mvps.org/autoevents.htm).
  If this add-in from 2002 still works today, it adds the event
  `Sub Auto_NextSlide(Index as Long)` which is executed before the
  slideshow moves to the next slide. Index represents the SlideIndex
  of the Slide about to be displayed.
  See [installation notes](http://skp.mvps.org/aevents.htm).
- Using a full screen tranparent (99%) shape.
  When such a shape appears in the animation sequence, and if it has
  a hover trigger, then this trigger will be executed no matter where
  is the cursor on the screen.